# PhpStorm - execute multiple commands with one button

Tags: git, phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.1

I execute 3 commands very frequently - `git checkout master & git pull upstream master & git push`. Currently, when doing this through UI, it takes 2 clicks for checkout, 5 clicks for pull from upstream, 2 clicks for push.
I have tried figuring out how to put this line under a UI button, but can't find a solution.

Some places suggest trying something with Tools > Settings > External Tools, but that does not allow executing multiple commands at once; it requires you to specify the full path to the executable (git in this case), and that breaks at the first join.

Another potential solution was Command Line Tools, but it has the exact same problem as External Tools, not to mention it can't be put under a button.

Is there a way to do what I want? I'm 100% sure that many other people would find this useful, since this is a very common thing to do in any forked GIT project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use Tools > Settings > External Tools and just write a script?

```
#!/bin/bash
git checkout master & git pull upstream master & git push
```

(or a batch file if on windows)

Then just execute the one script.

Comment: I would have wished for a better solution, but I suppose this would also work. Will wait for some other answers, maybe someone has other ideas.

Comment: This is **the** solution.

Comment: Oh well, guess I'll use this then.

Answer (score 4):

You can try a `Compound` configuration and add several bash commands.

[image: Run/Debug configuration]

Doing so you will be able to run commands with one click.

[image: Run Compound command]

Comment: This is a run configuration. It has a different purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I could not add a script, but I still wanted to execute multiple commands at once. So I came up with **Tools > Settings > External Tools** and used bash as a program and separated the commands with a `;`. The bash itself receives the command with the argument `-c` and a string in *double* quotes.

```
Program: bash
Arguments: -c "echo 1; echo 2; echo 3"
```